# Timing between Maximized editor/Final build and not maximized editor are off

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I've made a scene which has a light turn on with a flicker, which is combined with a sound effect. When I play the scene normally, in the not maximized editor, the sound effect and light flicker syncs perfectly. When I try to run the scene "Maximized on play", or run the game in a final build, the sound and flicker are off.

I'm using this setup in my inspector:

[image]

WindowOn has the AudioSource with the sound effect(s), and a "LightFlickering" script, which activates and deactivates the Flickering object to simulate the light flicker.

LightFlickering.cs:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightFlickering : MonoBehaviour {

    public float flickerTime, waitTurnOff;
    public GameObject flickerObject;
    public AudioClip lightOff;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(flickering());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator flickering()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTurnOff);
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = lightOff;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(flickerTime);
        flickerObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong to cause this desync?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you'll run into because of variable frame rates and how WaitForSeconds works. *Anything* that makes your time per frame not evenly divide flickerTime will cause a desync with the audio. Drawing the game window a little bigger or smaller could easily cause this.

Suppose flickerTime is 0.1 seconds and you're running at 41 FPS (~24 milliseconds / frame). WaitForSeconds will check every frame if 0.1 secs or more has elapsed, and see this progression: 0.024, 0.048, 0.072, 0.096, 0.120. When it sees 0.120, it finishes and resumes the coroutine, toggling the light and starting the next WaitForSeconds. But now the audio and visual are desynced by 20 ms. You'll get another 20 ms of desync with every WaitForSeconds, and after just a few of those the desync would be quite noticeable.

In order to fix this, you need to change your code to not use a chain of WaitForSeconds but instead something like this:

```
float accum = 0;
float startTime = Time.time;
while(Time.time - startTime < flickerTime * 6)
{
    accum += Time.deltaTime;
    if(accum >= flickerTime)
    {
        accum -= flickerTime;
        flickerObject.SetActive(!flickerObject.activeSelf);
    }
    yield return 0;
}
//Switch audio clip etc.
```

This accounts for the extra time that WaitForSeconds will not.
However, even that could get out of sync eventually. An even more reliable way is to read the audio time from the clip, and use that:

```
while(Time.time - startTime < flickerTime * 6){
    float clipTime = GetComponent<AudioSource>().time;
    int flicker = (int)(clipTime / flickerTime);
    bool isOn = (flicker % 2) == 0;
    flickerObject.SetActive(isOn);
    yield return 0;
}
```